# Test if program exists in Bash Script - abbreviated version

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to use the abbreviated if then else to determine if ccze exists before using it... and I just cannot get that first part right...

```
test() {
    [  $(hash ccze) 2>/dev/null ] && echo "yes"  || echo "no"
}
```

The above is just test.. what am I doing wrong?  It does not matter if ccze exists or not - I'm getting "no"

Comment: Try without the square brackets

Answer (score 4):

```
testcmd () {
    command -v "$1" >/dev/null
}
```

Using it:

```
if testcmd hello; then
    echo 'hello is in the path'
else
    echo 'hello is not in the path'
fi
```

or

```
testcmd man && echo yes || echo no
```

or you could put *that* into a function:

```
ptestcmd () {
    testcmd "$1" && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
}
```

This way you'll have one function that does *testing* and a separate function that does *printing* dependent on the test result.  You may then use the one taht is appropriate for the situation (you may not always want output).

Answer (score 2):

## Suggestion #1 - Answer

```
some_function() {
  hash ccze &> /dev/null && echo "yes" || echo "no"
}
```

### Suggestion #2

Rename the function to something else because there is already the command `test`.

**Don't override.**

### Suggestion #3

Remove the square brackets. Even if, in any case, you want to use square brackets, use double square brackets. Single square brackets are deprecated.

#### Brain Food

- [Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck)
- [Check for a command in PATH](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/nonportable#check_for_a_command_in_path)
- [Obsolete and Deprecated Bash Syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)
- [hash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command#answer-86017)

Answer (score 0):

```
test() #(not a good name)
{
    if hash ccze 2>/dev/null; then
       echo yes
    else 
       echo no
    fi
}
```

should do it.

`command -v ccze >/dev/null` is also usable and fairly portable (not POSIX but works with most shells).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that but it was the one liner I wanted. I know that version works.

Meanwhile we figured it out...

```
test() { [ -x "$(command -v cckze)" ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"; }
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want swift scripts, you should skip needless process substitution and IO. `have_command(){ command -v cckze >/dev/null; }` or if you need the IO `have_command(){ command -v cckze >/dev/null && echo yes || echo no; }`

Comment: You should call your function something other than `test` to avoid overriding the `test` utility.